# What command do we use to create a folder in pycharm?

Tags: python, html, css, django, command

I was coding in python. I typed this code python3 manage.py startapp products in order to create a folder, and I tried to find the folder, but I did not see nothing appeared. May someone help me to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

## Follow these steps in terminal

```
mkdir products
cd products
```

## Create a virtual environment to isolate package dependencies locally

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate  # On Windows use `env\Scripts\activate`

pip install django

django-admin startproject products
cd products
django-admin startapp products
cd ..
```

you can now open folder in pycharm